# How to run two Worksheet_Change on one worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below, that works. Change a number in 1 column and the column to the right adds the date and time.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column <> 3 Then Exit Sub
    With Target.Offset(0, 1)
        .Value = Now
        .NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm AM/PM"
    End With
End Sub
```

I would also like to run this code on column 6.

Tried a lot of things `Else`, `ElseIf`, `End If` etc.

Closest I managed:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column <> 3 Then Exit Sub
    With Target.Offset(0, 1)
        .Value = Now
        .NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm AM/PM"
    End With
    
    If Target.Column <> 6 Then Exit Sub
    With Target.Offset(0, 1)
        .Value = Now
        .NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm AM/PM"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thankyou both very much, all solutions supplied are a good learning curve, I have opted to use the simplified version, as it is less code, (which is always good), I am very proficient at Applescript, so I can figure how it works, again appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first 'If' prevent that the script continue if the target column is not 3, thus it won't execute when the column is 6.

All you have to do is change your mind, and create conditions for the desired execution.

```
If Target.Column = 3 Then
    With Target.Offset(0, 1)
    .Value = Now
    .NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm AM/PM"
    End With
ElseIf Target.Column = 6 Then
    With Target.Offset(0, 1)
    .Value = Now
    .NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm AM/PM"
    End With
End If
```

Or simplifying:

```
If Target.Column = 3 Or Target.Column = 6 Then
    With Target.Offset(0, 1)
    .Value = Now
    .NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm AM/PM"
    End With
End If
```

Comment: As the code is the same for column 3 and column 6, I see no reason why not to simplify it to `If Target.Column = 3 or Target.Column = 6 Then` and remove the `ElseIf`-branch

Comment: I tried to follow @Budgie logic, but that's a better solution.